# How do I display file modification time (linux) as "Nov 8 12:00" format?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, date, timestamps

The format I want is "Nov 8 12:00". It is the format you get by using the `ls -l` command. It is month, day of the month, hour and minute.
I tried `stat -c %Y filename` which gives time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch and I tried `date -d @resultFromStat`. It gives me unnecessary extra output like below.

> Fri Feb 13 16:31:30 PST 2009

I am trying to use bash in perl.

Comment: What command? You do not say what command/programming language etc you are using. Please edit question to make it clear.

Comment: `man date` `date -d @$(stat -c %Y .) "+%b %d %H:%M"`

Comment: Technically, the `ls -l` date format in the POSIX locale is `Nov 8 12:00` for dates in between 6 months ago and now, and `Mar 4 2018` for dates in the future or more than 6 months old. So do you want the date in the POSIX locale `ls -l` format or in the `%b %e %H:%M` format?

Comment: I believe I want it in ls -l format because answer from ctrl-alt-delor format worked but it  gave me extra 0 in front of "Oct 04 20:28" when I ran the answer from ctr-alt-delor.

Comment: When  Stéphane said "in ls -l format" the implication is that the format *changes* based on the file's age. Do you want the format to change, or do you always want it in the one format?

Comment: @ Jeff Schaller I want the format to change to based on file's age like ls -l. I believe the best way is to use ls -l and then extract the output from there.

Comment: @ Everyone. Thank you for your comment. I believe best way is to just use ls -l and not try to use stat and convert from there.